# Play/Pause key event is not respected during playback in react native for android tv

Tags: react-native, android-tv, tvapplicationcontroller

I have published a react native application to google play store for android tv.

For tv, I have received notification for:

> Play/Pause key event is not respected during playback
> Your media apps that play video or music content must respect the play/pause key during playback. Please refer to our Media Play/Pause documentation and Update the Playback State documentation for details.
> For example, your app does not pause the video being played when pressing the pause button on the Android TV controller.

How do I fix this issue for react-native android TV apps?

Answer (score 0):

try adding play/pause Event Listeners

```
  const _tvEventHandler = new TVEventHandler();    
  const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(false);

 
   const _enableTVEventHandler = () => {
_tvEventHandler.enable(this, function (cmp, evt) {
  console.log(evt);
  if (evt && evt.eventType === 'right') {
    console.log(evt.eventType);
  } else if (evt && evt.eventType === 'up') {
    console.log(evt.eventType);
  } else if (evt && evt.eventType === 'left') {
    console.log(evt.eventType);
  } else if (evt && evt.eventType === 'down') {
    console.log(evt.eventType);
  } else if (evt && evt.eventType === 'select') {
    setIsPaused(!isPaused);
  }
});
```

};